# How to match \n\n using perl one liner?

Tags: perl

My Sample file:

```
As I Come Into Your Presence 
Key: F

1 As I come into Your presence
Past the gates of praise
Into Your sanctuary
Till we are standing face to face 
And look upon Your countenance
I see the fullness of Your glory
And I can only bow down and say 

Chorus:
Your awesome in this place
Mighty God
You are awesome in this place
Abba Father
You are worthy of all praise
To You our lives we raise
You are awesome in this place
Mighty God
    <--- Empty line here
    <--- Empty line here
```

I wrote this perl one-liner to get `<i></i>` tags around the entire chorus block:

```
perl -p0e "s#Chorus:(.*?)\n\n#<i>Chorus:$1</i>#gsm" file
```

The result:

```
As I Come Into Your Presence 
Key: F

1 As I come into Your presence
Past the gates of praise
Into Your sanctuary
Till we are standing face to face 
And look upon Your countenance
I see the fullness of Your glory
And I can only bow down and say 

<i>Chorus:</i>%
```

I can't get the desired result where the `</i>` tag would be printed after the entire chorus after the `Mighty God`.

Where is the error? How can I achieve this?

Comment: perl -p0e "s#Chorus:(.*?)\n\n#<i>Chorus:\$1</i>#gsm" file .escape the $

Comment: Use single quotes on the commandline to wrap perl expressions otherwise the shell expansion will kick in. Alternatively, escape the `$` like @sigmatha suggests.

Comment: Thanks @sigmalha for the solution. That did it!

Comment: @sigmalha: Please post your comment as a solution

Comment: `-0` doesn't slurp the whole file. It's `-0777` that does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution would work if you just put it in single quotes instead of double quotes. You should pretty much *always* use single quotes for one-liners from the shell, no matter what language/interpreter you're running, to keep shell interpolation from messing things up.

In your code:

```
perl -p0e "s#Chorus:(.*?)\n\n#<i>Chorus:$1</i>#gsm" file
```

The `$1` is being expanded by the shell before it ever gets to Perl, so Perl sees this:

```
perl -p0e "s#Chorus:(.*?)\n\n#<i>Chorus:</i>#gsm" file
```

and happily deletes your chorus.  If you use single quotes instead:

```
perl -p0e 's#Chorus:(.*?)\n\n#<i>Chorus:$1</i>#gsm' file
```

it will work as intended.

Note, however, that the `-0` means any NUL characters that creep into the input will still cause Perl to split it into multiple records at that point. A more correct solution would be to use `-0777` instead, which tells Perl that no value should split the input; it is treated as a single record no matter what data it contains.

```
perl -p0777e 's#Chorus:(.*?)\n\n#<i>Chorus:$1</i>#gsm' file
```

Answer (score 2):

escape the $

```
perl -p0777e "s#Chorus:(.*?)\n\n#<i>Chorus:\$1</i>#gsm" file.
```

also as @Kenney mention in the comment:

```
Use single quotes on the commandline to wrap perl expressions otherwise the shell expansion will kick in.
```

Comment: In my opinion, it's a bad idea to escape individual characters like that; too easy to miss some.  Single-quotes is a more reliable approach.

Comment: yep.it's just a quick and dirty way.